# Selenium / Python & Captcha: Different behaviour when headless = True

Tags: python, selenium, captcha, headless-browser

I wrote a little Python script using Selenium and I have different behaviour between the "headed" mode and the headless mode.

Everything looks good in headed mode, the page loads correctly. With the headless mode, I need to validate some captcha before the page load...

I only change `options.headless` from `False` to `True` for my tests (code below).

I use the Chrome's profile and I imagined that once I validated the captcha with the headed mode, it will work fine with the headless mode: I'm wrong...

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

service = Service("./webdriver/chromedriver")
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                 "Chrome/95.0.4638.54 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=./profile")
options.add_argument("--profile-directory=default")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.headless = False

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
driver.get("https://[REDACTED]")
```

Did you experience the same behaviour? If yes, how did you manage it?

thanks!

R.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had to go through a CAPTCHA with selenium python too. I don't know if it can help you, but the way it can be solved is to solve the CAPTCHA manually and then your code will continue :
In your code, when you arrive at the CAPTCHA, put:

```
# launch your browser with selenium as you did

import time
time.sleep(30)  # you will have 30sec to solve the CAPTCHA, then program will resume

#continue your code here
```

This way, all the steps are automated except the CAPTCHA solving, and you will be able to stay in your original headless mode.

Comment: It could be a workaround! I did a condition where if the debugger port is open, I add  `options.add_experimental_option("debuggerAddress", "127.0.0.1:9014")` and I can resolve the captcha. Else, the options `options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])` and `options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)` are set (I can not mix the 3 options).